# convert Buffer to String

Tags: javascript, react-native, buffer

I am trying to convert a metatag to plain text using the Buffer.from and .toString(). My goal is to display an array of the keywords using the .map method within my main function. But I notice some strange behavior. My map function isn't displaying the keywords correctly.

Keywords: `[79, 0, 98, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 59, 0, 80, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 59, 0]`

`const buffer = Buffer.from(Keywords);`

buffer:
`{"data": [79, 0, 98, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 59, 0, 80, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 59, 0], "type": "Buffer"}`

`const bufferString = buffer.toString();`

bufferString: `Obst;Person;`

after returning the bufferString to my main method: `Set {"O", "", "b", "s", "t", ";", "P", "e", "r", "o", "n"}`

I also tried to use .split()
`const words = bufferString.split(";");` => `["Obst", "Person", ""]` but when i return this array, then my map function displays only the letter O from the first keyword and no letters from the second keyword.

The strange thing is that when i create a new Array like `let keywords = ["Obst", "Person", ""];` everything is working correctly.

So something must be odd with the strings coming from the buffer.

Comment: What encoding is this keywords array?

Comment: @Gavin the encoding ist "ucs2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UCS-2 is a character encoding standard in which characters are represented by a fixed-length 16 bits (2 bytes)

With the encoding known you can decode properly and get the data as expected:

```js
const data = [79, 0, 98, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 59, 0, 80, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0, 111, 0, 110, 0, 59, 0]
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data)
const utf16Decoder = new TextDecoder('UTF-16')

console.log(utf16Decoder.decode(dataBuffer)) // Obst;Person;
```

I think it's trying to decode as utf8 by default and getting upset at the unrenderable null bytes between every character:

[image]